# Is it necessary to use foreign keys in this case?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have a table in MYSQL with `name`, `level` and `xp` columns, and another one with `level`, `requiredxp`. I want to make that if a user reaches the `requiredxp` with their `xp` value they change their level.

Is it necessary to use primary keys and foreign keys to make this automatically without having to send the information to the server, check for the `xp`, and set a function with a lot of if statements to check for the `requiredxp` in the other table, and then if it's greater than the user `xp` change the `level`?

I'm relatively new to MySQL so please correct me if I'm wrong in something :)

Comment: No foreign keys are not necessary in your use case. In your use case you would simply have a sub query or join to determine the user's level based on required xp and the current user's xp. You would not want to store the user's level separately in a user table because that may cause synchronization issues if you were to ever wish to change the required xp for a level.

Comment: This doesn't strictly answer your question, but, my opinion: don't rely on database constraints to enforce your application's essential logic. You have a lot more flexibility to handle changes and strange edge cases (in your domain, perhaps you add a magical item that automatically confers an extra level) in code than via database constraints.

Comment: So leave it without any foreign nor primary keys, and..?

Comment: I'm not sure if Dan J was getting at that, but you DO want to implement keys, for data integrity, IMO... without question.  I like the subquery approach in the first users comments. It leaves the "rule" of what level you can be in the level table.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a LEVEL table with two columns: level and requiredExp. Then, a second table called PLAYER with the columns: name, experience, level.

The primary key on the first table is level. The primary key on the second table is the player_id or something. The column level on the PLAYER table is a foreign key referencing the LEVEL table. This way, on your code, you will be able to ask, if PLAYER x has EXPERIENCE y, then you can do an update to player's level on the PLAYER table.

I hope this helps!